# How did the custom to recite Shir Hashirim after the Seder arise?

Tags: minhag, passover-seder-hagada, provenance, shir-hashirim

It seems from [here for example, question 148](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/03/30/pesach-the-seder/) that it is a custom to recite Shir Hashirim after the Seder.

It says,

> According to the Midrash, Shir Hashirim is an allegorical song
>   describing the mutual devotion between Hashem and the Jewish people.
>   Many of the verses refer to the miraculous Exodus from Egypt.

What is the origin of this custom – who started it and when?

Answer (score 4):

[Nitei Gavriel Pesach 2 Chapter 105:6:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=570&hilite=) brings it in the name of the Shela 170:1 which bases this  Minhag on Mesechtas Sofrim 14:18.