# Shir HaShirim on Sabbath Eve

Tags: sources-mekorot, shir-hashirim, erev-shabbat

What are the earliest sources that reference the recitation of Shir HaShirim on Erev Shabbos? (Bearing in mind the dates of redaction of various Midrashim).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11163/759

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37110/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav [Yehuda Leib Maimon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Leib_Maimon) discusses this question [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33579&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=).

The earliest explicit source he finds is in Chemdas Yamim (he acknowledges the controversy around this sefer but indicates his defense of the work), who simultaneously mentions a "wide spread" custom to use musical instruments for Kabbalas Shabbos. He finds no corroboration for the latter custom, but suggests a source for Shir HaShirim from the Zohar Vayera 98a-b where Rabbi Eliezar reveals the secrets of Shir HaShirim to Rabbi Akiva specifically on Erev Shabbos.